# Page Title and Site Title Configuration DNN 7

Tags: asp.net, .net, seo, dotnetnuke

Currently I am using DNN 7 and when I view a page the Tab looks something like below

SiteLogo SiteName > PageTitle

I am unable to find any settings within DNN that will allow me to specify how I want this to appear. I would like all my pages to appear like below

SiteLogo PageTitle | SiteName

Is there any way to manage this setting within DNN or will this have to be configured within the code somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is automatic if you leave the "Page Title" setting blank within the settings for the individual page.

To accomplish what you desire you will need to customize the settings on a page-by-page basis.